# How to input some values to each column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to add column names before each values of each column with pandas?

Initial dataframe:

```
name Math Physics 

Jack 90    100

Tom  70     95
```

Add column names into each column:

```
name        Math       Physics 

name:Jack   Math:90    Physics:100

name:Tom    Math:70    Physics:95
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add DataFrame converted to strings by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to columns names:

```
df = df.columns + ':' + df.astype(str)
print (df)
        name     Math      Physics
0  name:Jack  Math:90  Physics:100
1   name:Tom  Math:70   Physics:95
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) for add values from right side:

```
df = df.astype(str).radd(':').radd(df.columns)
print (df)
        name     Math      Physics
0  name:Jack  Math:90  Physics:100
1   name:Tom  Math:70   Physics:95
```